# Use CURDATE() function

Tags: mysql, datamapper, codeigniter

How to use CURDATE() function to find records between two dates using DATAMAPPER library. PHP CodeIgniter with MySQL. I am trying something like

```
    $scanObj = new Scanned_info();
    $scanObj->where('','CURDATE() BETWEEN checked_in AND checked_out');
    $scanObj->limit($config["per_page"], (($page - 1) * $config['per_page']));
    $scanObj->order_by('id','desc');
    $response = $scanObj->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove first parameter prom your where clause.

```
$scanObj->where('CURDATE() BETWEEN checked_in AND checked_out');
```